В консоли разработчика код срабатывает, а из документа нет. Почему?
Всем привет!
У меня есть фрейм, я хочу его изменить. Я хочу сделать фоновую картинку на 50% меньше. Когда я открываю код фрейма на странице и меняю там размеры в css, все ок.
Но когда я этот код меняю в файле, на странице размеры не меняются. Почему??
Код:
<iframe src="https://yandex.ru/sprav/widget/rating-badge/243203034082?type=rating" width="150" height="50" frameborder="0">
#document (https://yandex.ru/sprav/widget/rating-badge/243203034082?type=rating)
<html><head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
            <title>Rating</title>
            <style>
                html, body {
                    width: min-content;
                    min-width: unset;
                    max-width: unset;
                    height: min-content;
                    min-height: unset;
                    max-height: unset;
                    margin: 0;
                    background-color: unset;
                }
                
                .RatingBadgeWidget {
                    display: block;
                    width: 150px;
                    height: 50px;
                    background-repeat: no-repeat;
                    background-position: center;
                    background-size: 50%;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <a class="RatingBadgeWidget" target="_blank" href="//yandex.ru/maps/org/243203034082/reviews?utm_source=badge&amp;utm_medium=rating&amp;utm_campaign=v1" style="background-image:url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-altay/774406/badge_rating_light_4.0/orig);"></a>        
</body></html>
</iframe>

фрейм и картинки должны быть на 50% меньше.

Потому что у скриптов на твоей странице нет доступа к содержимому фрейма.

что можно сделать, чтобы было так, как мне надо? Возможно ли вообще сделать так, как я хочу?

Ничего нельзя сделать. Доступ к IFRAME с чужого домена (без очень серьёзных танцев с бубнов владельцев этого домена) невозможен. И конечно Яндекс не будет для вас «танцевать».

я правильно понимаю, что он определяет чужой домен по ссылке в фрейме src="https://yandex.ru/sprav/widget/rating-badge/243203034082?type=rating"?
Т.е. в свой какой-то фрейм обернуть со своими стилями не вариант? Принудительные стили применить тоже не вариант?..

У тебя в принципе нет доступа к внутренностям iframe - стилям, скриптам и т.д.

Поскольку на данной странице не видно каких-либо специальных запросов или скриптов, можно просто вырезать нужный кусок кода и вставить его себе на страницу. А на своей странице уже можно делать любые изменения.
<style>
    .RatingBadgeWidget {
        display: block;
        width: 150px;
        height: 50px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: 50%;
    }
</style>
<a class="RatingBadgeWidget" target="_blank" href="//yandex.ru/maps/org/243203034082/reviews?utm_source=badge&amp;utm_medium=rating&amp;utm_campaign=v1" style="background-image:url(https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-altay/774406/badge_rating_light_4.0/orig);"></a>

